# How to get page to scroll to a section when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I'm trying to get my page to scroll to a specific point on my page if there is errors after submitting a form. My page doesn't scroll down. I'm using Laravel 4.

Jquery

```
$('.submit_btn').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#form-messages').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

my contact.blade.php

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="contact_form">
        <!-- <div id="form-messages"></div> -->
        @foreach($errors->all(':message') as $message)
          <div id="form-messages" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{ $message }}
          </div>
        @endforeach()
        {{ Form:: open(array('url' => 'contact_request')) }}
          {{ Form:: text('name', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Name')) }}
          {{ Form:: email('email', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Email')) }}
          {{ Form:: text('subject', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Subject')) }}
          {{ Form:: textarea ('message', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Your Message')) }}
          {{ Form::submit('SEND', array('class' => 'submit_btn')) }}
        {{ Form:: close() }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

So I half managed to to what I needed execpt it jumps up after hitting the id. For example when I click the submit button the page scrolls down to the correct section of my page but then it jumps up a bit to another section.

Here is my updated form

```
{{ Form:: open(array('url' => 'contact_request#contact')) }}
          {{ Form:: text('name', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Name')) }}
          {{ Form:: email('email', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Email')) }}
          {{ Form:: text('subject', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Subject')) }}
          {{ Form:: textarea ('message', '', array("class" => "form-control", 'placeholder' => 'Your Message')) }}
          {{ Form::submit('SEND', array('class' => 'submit_btn')) }}
        {{ Form:: close() }}
```

Comment: Are you using a `submit` button and moreover,are button's being added dynamically?

Comment: Yes I'm using a submit button and the button is static